# Личная галерея пользователя

Tags: jquery, php, javascript, kohana

Всем доброго времени суток!

Моя задача заключается в создании социальной сети(все основные возможности), после создания маломальского функционала, у меня возникла проблема с реализацией личной галереи пользователя, а проблема то в том что, я не знаю с чего начать и откуда так сказать "веревки вить" :D Подскажите, какие могут быть решения? Как сделать лучше? Заказчик требует, чтобы было нечто, похожее на галерею контакта.

Заранее Всем благодарен!

P.S. Работаю я на фрейворке Kohana 3.2

Comment: а ещё я тебе посоветую использовать фреймворк - CodeIgniter. Если ты начинающий прогер, то тебе будет намного проще! Там нету такой запарки с ООП.

Comment: Я рассматривал CodeIgniter, но всё таки Kohana мне как то больше нравится, да и привык я к ней)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Подключите javascript библиотеку для изображений - [Highslide](http://highslide.com/).
2. Выведите как в примерах этой библиотеки изображения при помощи php.

Допустим, у вас есть таблица в БД - images. Для каждой записи есть `user_id` - условие при котором вы выводите изображения. В этой таблицы у вас ссылки на изображения.

Comment: а используя этот плагин у меня получится открывать фотки по ссылке, пример: http://mydomain.com/username/photo, где <photo> - id фотографии?

Comment: в плагине есть методы, или можно сделать отдельно функцию.